# Get token from response headers in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, jwt, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get the Authorization token in the response from my laravel REST API with jwt

```
getData(type, token){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
headers.append("Dummy-header", "Nothing here");


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
  this.http.get(apiUrl+type, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res =>{
    var response = res.json();
    var newToken = JSON.stringify(res.headers.get('Authorization'));
    console.log("New Token: "+newToken);
    resolve(response);
  }, (err) => {
    reject(err)
  });
}); 
}
```

But console log in new token its getting null
I check chrome inspector and got this
[Chrome xhr from network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZx4n.png)

The one with initiator "Other" had the Authorization token in response

[Chrome xhr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggzxy.png)

Comment: Hey Alex, I might be missing something here, but I think normal pattern is - you request server to auth user first and response body provides you with JWT token, then you use such token as a header for all the API requests. In your case I think this logic is somewhat different.

Comment: Yeah, in every request the token gets refreshed and added to the response header, so thats why I'm trying to get it from the response header.